# Why is the package "label" useful to create europecvs

Tags: europecv

I have used LaTex just a couple of times and hence I know just a few things. I have an assignment where I should create my own cv, and for this reason I decided to do a search on the web to find a tool or a package that could have helped me, and in fact I found the package `europecv`, but now I have a few problems:

1. Why do I need to include the package `label` to not get this error (what is it used for?):

> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{europecv} (followed by:
>   )
>
> Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{europecv} (followed by:)

2. How to insert a further space between 2 `ecvitems` of a `ecvsection`? I have tried with `\\`, but it seems not to work.
3. I would like to change the title of the cv. This is the current one:

> Europepass
>
> Curriculum Vitae

4. If I `usepackage{label}`, when I compile, I get this error. Is this because the package `label` is not included by default in the MacTex? If yes, how can I integrate this new package:

[image]

Remember that my main problem is the point 1.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{europecv}

\usepackage{label} %


\ecvLogoWidth{12mm}

\ecvname{name}
\ecvaddress{address}
\ecvtelephone{0010101010}
\ecvemail{email@email.fame}
\ecvnationality{human}
\ecvdateofbirth{stuff}
\ecvgender{male}

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}

\ecvpersonalinfo[10pt]


\ecvsection{Education}
\ecvitem{School}{Bullshits’ School}
\ecvitem{Date}{1900-2900}
\ecvitem{Country}{earth}
\ecvitem{Qualification Awarded}{None} \\


\ecvsection{Skills and Competences} 
\ecvitem{Languages spoken}{Chinese, Japanese, Korean, English, Finnish, German}

\end{europecv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm, could you provide the community with some sample code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Okay, if it's not working due to the `label` package, that's fine. But at least it should be something that incorporates all of the stuff mentioned in your post. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and replicate your problem.

Comment: Apart from the example missing `\usepackage{graphicx}`, it compiles fine for me. No package called `label` required.

Comment: Yes; `europecv` uses `\includegraphics` internally; I haven't the faintest idea why it doesn't do `\RequirePackage{graphicx}`, which is the accepted practice when a package is used by a class.

Comment: Never heard about `label.sty`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the package `label` does not correct the error, it merely causes another error before you encounter the original error. In fact, the `label` package [does not exist](http://ctan.org/pkg/label) on CTAN as of writing.

The error you reported is actually the second error reported by LaTeX. The first error (the one you should be looking at) is:

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \draweuropasslogo ->\includegraphics 
>                                      [width=\ecv@logowidth ]{europasslogo}
> l.14 \begin{europecv}
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

From this, you can determine that [`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is not loaded, but is used internally by the `europecv` class. So adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` solves the problem, and your MWE compiles without error.

The class author(s) really should have put `\RequirePackage{graphicx}` inside the class, since this is the way to ensure all dependencies are satisfied at compile-time.